# Pass a QT label from false to true

Tags: c++, qt

Good evening, I am playing a monopoly style game, when I fall into the cell I would change it to the visibility to be true, now the problem is when the second player rolls, I cannot tell you that if the label is true that I pay a tax

```
if(ui->lblPropiedadJugador->setVisible(true)){
 // Instrucciones de pago
 }
```

It shows me the following error could not convert void to boolean.
Does anyone know if I can solve it, I would appreciate it very much

Comment: your setVisible() method returns nothing. you cant use it inside a if statement

Answer (score 1):

The function `QWidget::setVisible()` returns `void`. You should instead use
`if (!ui->lblPropiedadJugador->isHidden())`.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I've been trying to solve that for many hours, thanks really

Comment: You are welcome. You should consider mark the answer correct.

Comment: Why not [`isVisible`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#visible-prop)?

Comment: Because my weird brain somehow searches for `isHidden()` first :D `isVisible()` is better in this case.